# Python function not calling when called w/out error

Tags: python, function

So I'm programming a text-based video game for a lark and one of the situations  is if enemy health is less than 1 than it does a whole bunch of things (Mostly modifying variables and printing lines) then it should call a function. Problem being it's not calling. The function is being read and checked against the defined function, but it's not executing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
 if enemy_hull < 1:
    print (enemy_name + " breaks up as explosions rack the hull! You've won!")
    scrap = scrap + randint(27,67)
    scrapStr = str(scrap)
    missile_count = missile_count + randint(1,8)
    missile_countStr = str(missile_count)
    shields = 60
    shieldsStr = str(shields)
    print ()
    print ()
    print("Your ship has " + shieldsStr + " shields and " + hullStr + " Hull Strength. You have " + scrapStr + " scrap and " + missile_countStr + " missiles.")
    time.sleep(3)
    FTLJump()
```

That's the function in question at the end, FTLJump, and it's being read but not executed. https://repl.it/Blt4/98 is the full code if anyone wants to take a looksie. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain again what `FTLJump()` is supposed to do? You are only declaring global variables in the function definition

Comment: It'd be easier to check the full code but it basically it asks you for an input, gives you random event based on the event, then either starts a "battle" or commences a store event where you can repair damage. It's supposed to loop so you can basically repeat the events multiple times and the problem is it's not looping the way it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FTLJump function only declares global variables and exits: there is no code inside. There is an indentation issue in that function.

Comment: An answer should actually anwer a question and it should not end with a new one

Comment: Stack Overflow looks like a dangerous place to hang around with 1 point of reputation : I can't answer as a comment...

Comment: I think you are right, looking at the code in the link OP provided there is definitely an indentation issue inside of the `FTLJump()` function. Maybe you should edit your post to tell them rather than ask them.

Comment: Adrien only has one point of reputation, and thus isn't allowed to comment yet.  (I think you're correct, Adrien, and should rephrase your answer as an answer rather than a question; I share your suspicion that it's an indentation issue in FTLJump().)

Comment: Thanks for the edit proposal. :)

It's a funny thing to create an account here after years of using Stack Overflow. You feel unable to do anything (I first created my account to upvote a neglected comment -- which I still couldn't do afterwards), but I understand now why the posts here are always such quality content!

Comment: Bottom line, define indentation problem? I keep having problems with the indentation here and I'm not sure what you mean by the function being empty.

Comment: Ah, yes. There we go. I indented everything one tab over and now It works. Thanks for help guys, I'm a bit new to python so it didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, Python is very strict on the indentation: this is what defines the blocks (if, for, while, functions, classes).
Also, I would split your project in several files. One main.py file where you do all the procedural stuff you're doing (not indented part), and another one, say my_stuff.py, that you would import via "import my_stuff" at the beginning of the main, such that you would call you functions like so: my_stuff.some_function(...). It would be clearer. Have a look around there: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html (beware of your Python version)

It's otherwise a good start!

Comment: Fair enough but do you know how I can do that on ChromeOS? The only reason I'm using a web IDE on my home pc is that the project started on my chromebook, as it's a school project, so do you know if I can use the text editor included and save it as a .py or do I need to download something new?

Comment: Sure! ChromeOS is essentially a Linux distribution, so you're on the perfect OS for coding. If you use a standard text editor, you will have to use the command line to navigate to your project folder (using the command "cd your_dir") and type "python myfile.py" (or "python3 myfile.py" if using Python 3.x) to execute your program.
Otherwise, I'm not aware of the recommended IDEs in Python. I use Jupyter, which is very trending and has a nice system of notebooks and cells (http://jupyter.org/). You'll also need to use the command line to install it, but I recommend you learn the console anyway!